# Creating a modal warning for an external link?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, php

I'm attempting to return a pop-up warning for users who click an external link on my site. The issue is, the functionality must still be there if JS is disabled. I think this would leave PHP as my only option, so would this be accomplished with a custom plugin? I've seen sites accomplish something similar with a separate redirect php include with the link destination in a query string. My experience developing Craft plugins is virtually nil so forgive my ignorance- but would that look like a plugin that finds and rewrites all the external links' hrefs on the existing page, returns the html for the modal (appends a fullscreen div to the dom), and populates a "continue to external link" anchor based on the original link in the query string? Am I on the right track here?

Thank you!

Comment: Pretty sure this is impossible (per my answer below)... If you think you've seen this done on other sites, please add a link to them so we can backwards-engineer it.

Answer (score 4):

**A modal cannot exist without JS... no matter how it is triggered.**

At best, you'd have the user navigate to an intermediate page, with "Forward" and "Back" buttons. That being said, the UX sounds pretty terrible in that case.

You're actually dealing with conflicting requirements:

- Must warn people before leaving site.
- Must be non-JS compatible.

Those two requirements will never really be in harmony.